# Iphone to WCF Service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wcf, web-services

I've been trying to get my iPhone application to talk to a WCF service. My application successfully connects/finds the web service, but, never seems to get a non-error response back. When I use visual studios wcf tester it works fine.

Xml format: `<mAccess><user></user><pwd></pwd></mAccess>`

Is there something wrong with how I'm structuring my head/body?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *soapMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<MobileAccess xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><mAccess><user>user</user><pwd>pwd</pwd><custID>0</custID></mAccess>
</MobileAccess></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];


[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IProviderDataService/MobileAccess" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];

[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: What is the error you get in/from WCF?

Comment: Which of the NSURLConnection methods do you use? Do you get any response or error message?

Comment: The error is an Internal Service Fault, the method is a POST.

Comment: Can you enable tracing at the server side to see if there is any error explaining why the server rejected the requets?

Comment: @carlosfigueira I'm trying to setup the log on the server side now. I didn't have access to it yesterday, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is one potential error in your construction of the URL request: The "Content-Length" must be set to the length of the HTTP body. This might be different from `[soapMessage length]` if non-ASCII characters in the message are converted to UTF-8.

So you should use the length of the data after the conversion:

```
NSData *bodyData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[bodyData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but in the example code for the OP, all characters are lower-ASCII, so it shouldn't make a difference in this specific case.

Comment: @carlosfigueira: yes, except if any field (e.g. the password) is in fact different from what is shown here. Since the OP asked about errors in the head/body, I decided to tell him about this potential problem.